# Magento 2 - What should be happen if customer fails the payment?

Tags: magento2, payment

I have been creating a `plug-in` to integrate `Magento 2` to `payU latam` web checkout gateway.

The order is created before the customer is redirected to the `gateway` and the state is `pending payment`. Then the store receives a `notification` about the process with the `results`.

What should I do if the `process fails`? What state and status I have to assign (on hold, cancel ...)? What about retrying the`payment?`